# Interacting With the Videogular Directive -- How To Do So?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, videogular

I'm using https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular and out of the box it works quite well, specifically.

```
<videogular vg-width="videoWidth" vg-height="videoHeight" >
    <video class='videoPlayer' ng-model="currentVideo">
        <source ng-src='{{currentVideo.videoLocation}}' test="{{currentVideo}}" type='video/ogg'></source>
    </video>
</videogular>
```

I'm unsure how I would, say since autoplay isn't true, get the video to play programmatically?
I know I could inside my controller that contains the above markup, call `angular.element()` then call `.play()` but from what I've read that seems wrong. That I shouldn't be calling `angular.element()` inside any controller.

What should I do? Should I create a directive that does this? Where is the best place to put the logic for "*playing*" and "*pausing*" a video (fwi, I want to have two videos on screen and once the first is over, do a few things then play the second).

Comment: As you say you shouldn't be doing any DOM manipulation in a controller but rather this should be handled in a directive, depending on your scenario and what videogular offers it may be easiest to create a "plugin" for videogular, modify the existing videogular directive (problem here being you'll have to merge your changes to update to new versions) or create your own directive that uses "require" to get the controller from videogular.

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday we've exposed the API to be accesible through $scope, so you could access all methods available.

You could check the API [here](https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/wiki/Videogular%27s-API).

This release is not yet available through bower, we're planning to do that this weekend.

**UPDATE**

The best way to know when a video have been completed is to add a scope function in your controller.

```
$scope.onCompletePlayer1 = function() {
    console.log("on complete 1");
};

$scope.onCompletePlayer2 = function() {
    console.log("on complete 2");
};
```

Then add in your HTML those functions in your `videogular` directives.

```
<videogular vg-complete="onCompletePlayer1()" ...></videogular>
<videogular vg-complete="onCompletePlayer2()" ...></videogular>
```

And finally add `vg-complete` as a $scope function in `videogular.js`:

```
\\Line 159
vgComplete: "&" 

\\Line 507
$scope.onComplete = function(event) {
    vg.setState(VG_STATES.STOP);
    $scope.$emit(VG_EVENTS.ON_COMPLETE);
    $scope.vgComplete();
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

We will try to add this in the next release, so maybe you want to wait a couple of days.

Comment: Do you have an example on how I'd do this? What it means to access through $scope?

Comment: btw for some reason when I updated my videogular.js file with the one on the repo it's ignoring my width and height settings.

Comment: We've been pushed a new version with what you need, just take a look to the example provided in the latest version available at Github project.